# Scrape dropdown options with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to webscrape an option list with BeautifulSoup to get the list of Automotive OEMs. As I just started coding I would higly appreciate your input! Thanks in advance!! :)

Desired output (remove "Make" as first entry, but list all other options):

```
Acura
Alfa Romeo
Aston Martin
Audi
Bentley
...
```

Output as of now:

```
Make
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Inputs/URLs to scrape: 
URL = ('https://www.motortrend.com/cars/')
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

select_tag = soup.find('select')
options = select_tag.find_all("option")
for option in options:
    print(option.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The data comes from a different page and is hydrated into the html. Either use a webdriver or use this instead:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.motortrend.com/api/v2/findyournextcarform/makes')
response.json()
```

output:

```
{'data': {'makes': [{'slug': 'acura', 'displayName': 'Acura'},
   {'slug': 'alfa-romeo', 'displayName': 'Alfa Romeo'},
   {'slug': 'aston-martin', 'displayName': 'Aston Martin'},
   {'slug': 'audi', 'displayName': 'Audi'},
   {'slug': 'bentley', 'displayName': 'Bentley'},
   {'slug': 'bmw', 'displayName': 'BMW'},
   {'slug': 'bollinger', 'displayName': 'Bollinger'},
   {'slug': 'bugatti', 'displayName': 'Bugatti'},
   {'slug': 'buick', 'displayName': 'Buick'},...]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Can you please post the entire code? I do not get the output, entering your code. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried this right now. It returns the makes. I'm not sure why the same wouldn't return on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The website you are trying to scrape has dynamic content which can not be scraped using *bs4* easily because *bs4* doesn't render the JavaScript. As a result, some of your content doesn't show up in the HTML source code.

So to get what you want you need to use something like *[selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)* which helps you render the page.

In your case, the thing you are trying to scrape is coming from another website via [API](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_intro.asp#:%7E:text=API%20stands%20for%20Application%20Programming,functionality%20of%20a%20web%20server.) which is fetched using JavaScript. But your code doesn't render JavaScript resulting in different output.

Here is a coding example using selenium to grab your desired output.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://www.motortrend.com/cars/")


try:
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select[@id="make-select"]//option')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

makers = [i.text for i in elements]
makers.pop(0)
print(makers)

driver.quit()
```

I suggest you to use selenium get more out of this website.